# can any body provide a link for downloading wordnet ontology 2.0??

Tags: java, eclipse, ontology

I already have downloaded wordnet2.0 full, but i am not getting how to use it as a graph because it consists of multiple RDF files. I want to use wordnet2.0 ontology as a graph in Eclipse. The following is the snippet of code that i am using for loading a ontology as a graph. I also want to know, Am i going in a right direction???

```
     URIFactory factory = URIFactoryMemory.getSingleton();
     URI graph_uri = factory.createURI("http://graph/");

    G graph = new GraphMemory(graph_uri);

    String fpath ="D:/Workspace/SSM/src/wordnet-wordsensesandwords.rdf";
    GDataConf graphconf = new GDataConf(GFormat.RDF_XML, fpath);

    GAction actionRerootConf = new GAction(GActionType.REROOTING);
    GraphConf gConf = new GraphConf();
    gConf.addGDataConf(graphconf);

   gConf.addGAction(actionRerootConf);
   // GraphLoaderGeneric.populate(graphconf, graph);
   GraphLoaderGeneric.load(gConf, graph);
    // General information about the graph
   System.out.println(graph.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/old-versions/

You can use this link to download the ontology and may use apache jena to query this

Once you have the results, you can represent it in the form of graph

You may also download wordnet in RDF format and can display it as graph using Protege tool

Comment: first of all thanks for answering, however you can see in my code i am giving path of an RDF file. by downloading wordnet2.0 from your mentioned link, how can i use it in my approach???

Comment: I dnt want to show the graph that's why i m not using protege. i just want to perform some calculations on wordnet ontology.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import nu.xom.Builder;
import nu.xom.ParsingException;
import nu.xom.ValidityException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import edu.mit.jwi.Dictionary;
import edu.mit.jwi.IDictionary;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IIndexWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.ISynset;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IWordID;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.POS;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try 
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\employees.xml"));      
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            System.out.println("*************************");
            String expression = "/Employees/Employee[@emplid='3333']/job";
            System.out.println(expression);
            String job = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
            System.out.println(job);
            System.out.println("*************************");



            String path = "C:\\Program Files\\WordNet\\2.1\\dict";
            URL url = new URL("file", null, path);

            IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(url);
            dict.open();

            IIndexWord idxWord = dict . getIndexWord (job, POS. NOUN );
            IWordID wordID = idxWord . getWordIDs ().get (0) ;
            IWord word = dict . getWord ( wordID );
            ISynset synset= word.getSynset();
            for (IWord w : synset.getWords())
            System.out.println(w.getLemma());




        }

        catch(Exception a)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
            }

    }
}
```

This is a sample code in which wornet can be queried for getting the synonyms of the word job from wordnet and using it to find similar terms like job from the RDF graph.

I have only worked with wornet for capturing related terms and hypernyms. Hope this may help